# simple css for table

Tags: css

When using html tables and css. I have used `rowspan="2"` to combine to rows together, but when i use background in the css, its not going right to the edges of the table.

Where am i going wrong? This is a really simple question i know.

Then the CSS is

```
#messages th{
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    color: #FF9912;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    border-right: solid 1px #666666;
}

#messages td{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Note: your PHP code is irrelevant. When debugging browser problems, look at the code the _browser_ sees (view source), not the code running on your server.

Comment: my css is on a separate page so will the (view source) not see this?

Comment: Can you post the HTML or a link to jsFiddle? Make sure you have disabled border collapsing on the table as well: `table { border-collapse: collapse; }`

Comment: thanks for your reply's but i managed to fix this. #mario - i did have the php code here with the html which was echoing back in to the table but Phrogz said it was irrelvant so i removed it. Cant win :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but aren't you coloring only the cells of the table, and not the spacing between the cells?

See this page:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_color

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the background on a `th` element, Tom Haws is probably correct that there is some sort of cell margin or padding in effect.  If you use firebug for Firefox or "inspect element" in chrome you can find out everything that is impacting `th` and turn them on and off.   You could also use `<thead>` to surround the headers, and assign the background color to that instead of `th`